# table header collapse when multiple tables inside panel-body bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: thats the second table in panel body][image: thats the first table in panel body]Im doing a page using **bootstrap panel and horizontal-tabmenu**. My first table is good in header alignment but the second and the third table headers are getting collapsed with the table body.Here is my sample I tried, please someone help me.

bootstrap.html

```
<div class = "panel panel-default">

        <div class = "panel-heading">
        <ul class = "nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div class = "table-responsive">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="contract_wise" class="table table-bordered table-colstriped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        <div class = "table-responsive">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="sdm_wise" class="table table-bordered table-colstriped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Menu 2</h3>
            <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the first table works excellent, but if I add a second table to the same panel body, the headers get collapsed.So please help me, thanks in advance.

my ajax for the problamatic table:

```
jQuery("#sdm_wise").dataTable({
            dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12'Bftri>>" + "<'row'<'col-sm-4'l><'col-sm-8'p>>",
            "sAjaxSource": "report_datatable_db.php?mode=sdm_wise_datatable",
            "bDestroy": true,
            "scrollX": true,
            "bInfo": true,
            select: true,
            buttons: [{

                    extend: 'collection',
                    text: 'Export',
                    buttons:[
                            {
                                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                                orientation: 'landscape',
                                pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspPDF</i>',
                                titleAttr: 'PDF'
                            },
                            {
                                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                                orientation: 'landscape',
                                pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspEXCEL</i>',
                                titleAttr: 'Excel'
                            },
                            {
                                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                                orientation: 'landscape',
                                pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                                text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-text-o">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspCSV</i>',
                                titleAttr: 'CSV'
                            },
                            {
                                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                                orientation: 'landscape',
                                pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                                text: '<i class="fa fa-files-o">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspCOPY</i>',
                                titleAttr: 'Copy'
                            }
                ]
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    pageSize: 'LEGAL'
                }
                ]
    });
```

And the method I used to extract data from mysql is below,

```
$rows = array();
        if (mysqli_multi_query($mysqli, $query)) {
            do {
                if ($result = mysqli_store_result($mysqli)) {
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                        $rows[] = $row;
                    }
                    $result->free();
                }
            } while (mysqli_next_result($mysqli));
        }
        mysqli_free_result($result);

        $results = array("aaData"=>$rows);
        echo json_encode($results);
        exit;
```

Comment: provide output of your code.That might help.

Comment: It is not clear where the table header get collapse?

Comment: so the first image is the second table in panel body and the second image is the first table in the panel body

Comment: for the problematic table, are you sure that the rows below and the header rows are in the same table? Please inspect element in your browser to check. Or else you need to provide more information for us to see. The information available is not enough for us to help you.

Comment: try using colspan attribute in your table header.

Comment: yes, I tried it but still the second, third and the forth ones gets collapsed, I have made so many changes but the panel-body class seems to be have problem with that and I have updated my question, please have a look.

Comment: guys, i have got a clue. When I click F12(browser console) in mozilla or chrome, then my second table headers get fixed and when switch back again it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed it by using classes like **bs-component, col-lg-12, and row**, Here is my html and the navigation tabs alignment.

index.html:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12"> 
<div class="bs-component">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs responsive">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Contract-Wise</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>    
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" onclick = "show_sdm()">SDM-Wise</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3" onclick = "show_sub()">SUB-Wise</a>
                        </li>
                               <li>
                            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4" onclick = "show_chain()">ChainName-Wise</a>
                        </li>
                     </ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade active in">
        <table id = "contract_wise" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover footable toggle-medium">
            <thead>
                <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
             </tbody>
         </table>
     </div>
```

By putting the **class row** at first and then declaring the table size as large **col-lg-12** and then the main important class **bs-component**, it is quite easy now to have any multiple tables for each navigation tabs.